# Error: Watchman was not found in PATH in windows

Tags: android, npm, react-native

I am learning `react-native` programming to develop android application. I was getting some error `unable to resolve module` when running application at runtime. I found some link for this and was suggested to run this command `react-native start --reset-cache` which in turn requires `watchman` on the system. I installed `watchman` then after I am unable to start `react-native`

> react-native start

```
D:\React Native\Example 1\ExampleOne>react-native start
Scanning 560 folders for symlinks in D:\React Native\Example 1\ExampleOne\node_m
odules (27ms)
 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐

 │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │

 │                                                                            │

 │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │

 │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │

 │  prefer.                                                                   │

 │                                                                            │

 │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │

 │                                                                            │

 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   D:\React Native\Example 1\ExampleOne

Loading dependency graph...Watchman:  Watchman was not found in PATH.  See https
://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html for installation instructions

React packager ready.

jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanco
nfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in
 your project.
  Error: Watchman was not found in PATH.  See https://facebook.github.io/watchma
n/docs/install.html for installation instructions
Watchman:  Watchman was not found in PATH.  See https://facebook.github.io/watch
man/docs/install.html for installation instructions
 ERROR  Watchman was not found in PATH.  See https://facebook.github.io/watchman
/docs/install.html for installation instructions
{"code":"ENOENT","errno":"ENOENT","syscall":"spawn watchman","path":"watchman","
spawnargs":["--no-pretty","get-sockname"]}
Error: Watchman was not found in PATH.  See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/
docs/install.html for installation instructions
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html
for common problems and solutions.

D:\React Native\Example 1\ExampleOne>
```

I have installed `watchman` successfully & when I am trying to execute `watchman` command then it is happening

[image]

[image]

This is where my `watchman` is installed. I have added this also in my PATH of my windows machine. `D:\React Native\Example 1\ExampleOne\node_modules\watchman`

`PATH` is D:\React Native\Example 1\ExampleOne\node_modules\watchman

I am not sure what could be the cause of this issue. Is my path is wrong or Am I pointing wrong directory of `watchman` ? Can anyone suggest me how I can resolve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get rid from this issue by uninstalling `watchman` npm package. Try to uninstall it globally and locally `npm uninstall -g watchman` `npm uninstall watchman`

Comment: Hi @TGMCians, this solution makes 'react-native start' to be able to run, but when running 'react-native run-android', I got an error saying: EPERM: operation not permitted, ... and the red error screen of the emulator says: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly. I am using Windows 7 btw, do you have any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, TGMCians, it doesn't solve the problem, but the error message in cmd is gone, the only problem is the red screen in the emulator, it still says:  'Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly', I am thinking about if I should install watchman back. What do you say?

Comment: @VincentZHANG Yep

Comment: Thank you @TGMCians, that brings back the error in cmd again, I am back to the starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.

so you should create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file or / and initialise your folder with npm install